# Font gets enlarged when rotating screen

Tags: 12.04, display-rotation

I have a new ThinkPad X220 Tablet with Kubuntu 12.04. When I rotate the screen 90° with a script, the fonts of all programs that I open after the rotation have ugly huge fonts.

[image: normal]

[image: rotated]

```
#!/bin/sh

# Find the line in "xrandr -q --verbose" output that contains current screen orientation and "strip" out current orientation.

rotation="$(xrandr -q --verbose | grep 'connected' | egrep -o  '\) (normal|left|inverted|right) \(' | egrep -o '(normal|left|inverted|right)')"

# Using current screen orientation proceed to rotate screen and input tools.

case "$rotation" in
        normal)
                # rotate to the left
                xrandr -o right
                xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus" rotate cw
                xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch" rotate cw
                xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser" rotate cw
                ;;
        right)
                # rotate to normal
                xrandr -o normal                                                                                                                                                                
                xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus" rotate none                                                                                                                           
                xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch" rotate none                                                                                                                         
                xsetwacom set "Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser" rotate none                                                                                                                           
                ;;                                                                                                                                                                              
esac
```

Comment: I'm not a kubuntu user... but I wonder if this old bug is your issue? (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184488) - if you follow the dupe, the only suggestion is to play with changing the dpi.  Can you confirm this is your issue?

Comment: Thanks, that helped. If you want, you can make this an answer to get the bounty points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*converted comment to answer*

Your Question appears to be related closely/or is the same as this old KDE [bug-report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184488).

Following the duplicate link it mentions a possible workaround

> A possible workaround for the problem:
>
> systemsettings -> appearance -> fonts force dpi to 96

Looking at the man-page for [xrandr](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xrandr.1.html) possibly you could try:

```
xrandr --dpi [dpi]
```

or possibly calling in your script `xrandr` twice, changing the `[dpi]` to one value, sleep for a second to allow the display to refresh, before calling the same routine again with the final `[dpi]` value - for example, `96`.